# What is the meaning of underscore in template?

Tags: c++, templates

What is the meaning of the underscore in template prototyping?
That is the example of template:

```
template<typename _Tp> _Tp* Mat::ptr(int i=0)
```

Why people add underscore before Tp?

Comment: Symbols beginning with a `_` are reserved for standard and compiler internal implementations.

Comment: "People" have probably looked at the standard library implementation, where the code often uses reserved names like `_Ty` to avoid collisions with user code. And then the user code starts to *also* use these names. Don't do that!

Comment: If it is third-party code (which the name `Mat::ptr` implies), it means the developer doesn't really know what they are doing.   Such identifiers, in any scope, are reserved for use by the implementation - for example, as macro names.   Since there may be a clash with the implementation (e.g. macros used in the standard library, or compiler-specific features) the behaviour is undefined.    If this sort of code is used WITHIN the implementation (e.g. standard headers, compiler intrinsics, etc) ... well, that's what these things are for.

Comment: names begining by 1 underscore folowed by a capital letter, declared at global namespace scope are reserved (not all names begining by a single underscore)

Comment: @Oliv -- "Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name **in the
global namespace**." [global.names]/1 (emphasis added). In addition, names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved **for any use** (as are names that contain two consecutive underscores).